# Number processing slower with asm.js

Tags: javascript, performance, asm.js

I did a few times ago what I called a plasma demo in plain JavaScript:

[image]

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/kwt4p8st/)

The idea is to use 2 oscillators (LFO) which have their frequency + phase driven by two oscillators each. Then we use those 2 main oscillator output to decide of the r, g, b of each point.

To test the quite new API asm.js, I've ported it to be fully 'typed' and in complete memory isolation.

The big issue I encountered is that it is way slower with asm.js than with plain JavaScript. Worse: When I comment 'use asm' to have the browser interpret the code, I get better results (30% faster) than when the compilation succeeds.

The memory I use is:

1. A byte array of the size of the canvas: this is the output that I will `putImageData` on the canvas.
2. Right after I consider I have a `float` array that stores the values for the LFOs (base / amplitude / frequency / phase ), for 6 LFO.

I've made two versions, one fp32 and one fp64, none of which is fast (<50 ms per frame, when the plain object version is around 20ms).

Be sure to use a Browser that understands asm.js Firefox is one.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/L5r8rkrf/)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n8yme5z/)

After experimenting, a lot of time is spent evaluating the LFO value:

```
function oscillatorValueAt(heap_f64_Index, x) {
    heap_f64_Index = heap_f64_Index | 0;
    x = +x;
    var base = 0.0,
        amp = 0.0,
        freq = 0.0,
        phase = 0.0;

    heap_f64_Index = heap_f64_Index << 3;
    base = +heap_f64[(heap_f64_Index + 0) >> 3];
    amp = +heap_f64[(heap_f64_Index + 8) >> 3];
    freq = +heap_f64[(heap_f64_Index + 16) >> 3];
    phase = +heap_f64[(heap_f64_Index + 24) >> 3];
    return  +(base + amp * sin(freq * x + phase));
}
```

This is called several times per pixel in the tickPixels sub, with calls like:

```
vaty = +oscillatorValueAt(osc1, yD);
```

Could you help me to find why there isn't a speed boost?

Comment: I had an issue with not handling a return value, caused a massive 3x slow down.  I believe asm.js supports void functions, but it seems many things can cause hiccups while the code still validates and compiles as asm.  Wish I could tell you what the specific issue is here, but I'm not seeing anything. From what little experimentation I've done if FF doesn't say "disabled asm" then it compiled, otherwise your guess is as good as any. :(https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/is-it-really-using-asmjs/6754488050384896